# Why can't I click on "Edit Header" that's greyed and faded out?

Tags: microsoft-word

You can download the .docx at [Accessibility Resources - Oxford University Press](https://global.oup.com/academic/rights/permissions/accessibility/?cc=ca&lang=en&)

> Please complete this form [Accessibility Request Form](http://fdslive.oup.com/www.oup.com/academic/doc/academic/accessibilityrequestform.docx)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document is protected, so you can only edit certain sections

[image]

This will be intentional.